# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in Laravel 5.3 Email Queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I am willing to send email to list of email address using `queue`. Without using queue my code is working fine but with queue it's showing following error:

```
Exception in Queue.php line 86: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

    in /home/hizbul/Development/Projects/Laravel/fastskool/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php line 86
    at serialize(object(SendMessageToStudent)) in Queue.php line 86
    at Queue->createPayload(object(SendMessageToStudent), '') in DatabaseQueue.php line 81
    at DatabaseQueue->push(object(SendMessageToStudent)) in Dispatcher.php line 184
    at Dispatcher->pushCommandToQueue(object(DatabaseQueue), object(SendMessageToStudent)) in Dispatcher.php line 159
    at Dispatcher->dispatchToQueue(object(SendMessageToStudent)) in Dispatcher.php line 73
    at Dispatcher->dispatch(object(SendMessageToStudent)) in DispatchesJobs.php line 17
    at Controller->dispatch(object(SendMessageToStudent)) in MessageController.php line 49
    at MessageController->store(object(Request))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(MessageController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 55
    at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(MessageController), 'store') in Route.php line 189
    at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StaffAndAdmin.php line 40
    at StaffAndAdmin->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ModuleManager.php line 29
    at ModuleManager->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SwitchDatabaseConnection.php line 36
    at SwitchDatabaseConnection->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
    at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
    at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 68
```

I am using `database` as queue driver.

Following is my Queue job handler code:

```
    class SendMessageToStudent implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->data = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $student = $this->data;
        $arrStudent = (new Message())->getEmailAddressList($student);
        Mail::to($arrStudent)->send(new MessageSent($student));
    }
}
```

and dispatcher code:

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMessageToStudent($request));
```

I am expecting a feasible solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot serialize request. Only eloquent model can be serialized and unserialzed. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes

You should use `$request->all()` instead of `$request`. Since Request is treated as closure.

Comment: I was also doing same mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Try removing this line from constructor:

```
$this->message = new Message();
```

and, in the handle directly initialise it.

```
$student = $this->data;
$arrStudent = (new Message())->getEmailAddressList($student);
Mail::to($arrStudent)->send(new MessageSent($student));
```

Comment: @hizbul25 I faced a similar solution week back, it worked for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me in Laravel 5.6. 
I just added this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

And everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Serializable interface in your request class. I made BaseRequest class for that and all requests inherit from it.

```php
class BaseRequest extends FormRequest implements \Serializable
{

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return json_encode($this->all());
    }

    /** @inheritDoc */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $data = json_decode($serialized, true);
        $this->initialize($data);
    }

}
```