# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed when using queues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Here's my RequestMail.php file:

```
protected $phone;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->phone = $request->get('phone');
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('robot@bithub.tech')
                ->view('request')
                ->subject('Новая заявка на обмен криптовалют')
                ->with(['phone' => $this->phone]);
}
```

My controller:

```
Mail::to('request@domain.com')->queue(new RequestMail($request));
```

When i am trying to queue the mail, i am getting the following error: "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

**EDIT** updated the final code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using queues you cannot serialize Objects that contains closures, it's the way PHP works. Every time you push a job onto a queue, Laravel serializes its properties to a string that can be written to the database, but anonymous functions (e.g. functions that do not belong to any class) cannot be represented as a string value, thus they cannot be serialized. So basically when you push your `RequestMail` job onto the queue, Laravel tries to serialize its properties, but `$request` is an object that contains closures, so it cannot be serialized. To solve the problem you have to store in the `RequestMail` class only properties that are serializable:

```
protected $phone;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->phone = $request->get('phone');
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->from('robot@domain.com')
                ->view('request')
                ->subject('New request for exchange')
                ->with(['phone' => $this->phone]);
}
```

Doing such thing you are keeping only the properties of `$request` that you actually need, in this case the phone number, that is a string and it is perfectly serializable.

**EDIT**
I've realized just now that this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251488/serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed-in-laravel-5-3-email-queue?rq=1)

**EDIT 2** i've edited the code with the correct request parameter retrieval for further reference.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't use `$phone` variable in a view then, it returns nothing.

Comment: Try to initialize `$phone = $request->get('phone')` also make sure that you are using `Illuminate\Http\Request` class instance.

Comment: Initialize outside of `_construct` function?

Comment: No, always in the `__construct` function: `$this->phone = $request->get('phone')`