# Laravel queue : Job Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I have already tried resolve of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423512/serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed-when-using-queues) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475892/laravel-queue-serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed), finally, they do not resolve my problem.

I added job to my queue like this

```
public function successPayment(Request $request){

$command = Command::findOrFail($request->reference);

if($command->state == Command::PENDING){
        $command->state = Command::SUCCESS;
        $command->payed_at = now();

        if(!empty($oldCommandItem = session('renew_command')))
        {
            $commandItem = $command->items()->offers()->get()->first();
            $commandItem->application_id = $oldCommandItem->application->id;
            $commandItem->save();


            $notification = $user->notifications->last();
            $application = $commandItem->application;

            RestoreApplicationJob::dispatch(['application'=>$application, 'notification'=>$notification]);

            $next = route('application.show', $commandItem->application_id);
            session()->forget('renew_command');
        }

        $command->save();
    }
 }
```

And my Job

```
class RestoreApplicationJob implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $datas;

public $tries = 1;


public function __construct($datas)
{
    $this->datas = $datas;
}

public function handle()
{
    try{
        $application = $this->datas['application'];
        $notification = $this->datas['notification'];
        $application->activate();
        $tmp_data = $notification->data;
        $tmp_data['state'] = Opertation::SUCCESS;

        $notification->data = $tmp_data;
        $notification->save();
    }catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        Log::error($e->getTraceAsString());

        $tmp_data = $notification->data;
        $tmp_data['state'] = Opertation::FAILED;

        $notification->data = $tmp_data;
        $notification->save();
    }
}
```

}

I have this error :

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

I checked many times where it stucks but, don't find anything

Thank you for your help and sorry for my so bad english :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was so crazy...

It's just I call class `Opertation` instand of `Operation` inside Job. 
That throw Exception...